# Which is the best tool to display web statistics - Open Source and Paid

Tags: html, web-statistics

I would like to know which is best suited for displaying visitor stats in our websites
The key areas under our consideration are
1. User Count
2. Unique User Count
3. User Location

Regards,
naveenj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is free and it fits all your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is a self-hosted, Open Source competitor to Google Analytics written in PHP.

It can do 1) and 2) no problem.

The one thing it doesn't seem to be doing, at least not out of the box, is user location on city or at least regional level. It can get the country and the online provider, but nothing more detailed. Google's geolocation is probably unbeatable here.

The huge advantage of a self-hosted solution over something like Google Analytics is obviously that no third party gets hold of visitor data.

Comment: > thanks for the link. i was looking for google analytics getting confirmed. Will surely check out piwik but didnt like the fact that the piwik.org is down now(404). Thank you

Comment: @naveen you're welcome. I'm looking to use Piwik where I can, mainly out of privacy concerns. GA is fine, though, I use it in many projects myself, and they have a lot of interesting features. Piwik.org works for me right now, try again!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics - Now they also have numerous API so you can get all the data you want through PHP/your server.